# NodeJS Event emitter example

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying understand on how to let some function to run in the background, without interrupting any other codes, and work with events

For example:

```
class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {

    public async doSomeWork() {
        try {
            this.emit('begin');
            await function1();
            await function2();
            await function3();
            this.emit('success');
            console.log('done');
        } catch (err) {
            this.emit('error')
        }
    }
}

function mainWork() {
    const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();

    myEmitter.doSomeWork();
    myEmitter.on('success', () => { console.log('it is a success') })
    doSomeOtherWork1();
    doSomeOtherWork2();
}
```

Okay, so if I want to let `doSomeWork()` runs without interruption, and only emit events regarding its work once it is done to the caller, whether failed or success, how should I put it into work? And how to start `doSomeWork()` function without "awaiting" it to finish?

Thus there will be 2 codes running at the same time. The caller code that called `doSomeWork()` and then continue to run next codes like `doSomeOtherWork1()` and `doSomeOtherWork2()`, and `doSomeWork()` itself that is also run. `console.log()` will only be called when `doSomeWork()` done.

Can you please give an example? Because all examples I found are mostly about utilizing built-in functions that already exist. But, how to make one? Do I need async function for it?

Thank you

Comment: My first thought was: Use Workers (https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html), so I am documenting it here. Not sure if it fits.

Comment: It depends upon what your other functions are doing.  If they are doing CPU intensive stuff, then you will have to move them to worker threads in order to not impact the other code you're running.  If they are only using natively asynchronous operations (such as file I/O or networking), then they can run on their own without interfering with your other code.  So, we can't answer concretely without seeing the actual code for those other functions.

Comment: @jfriend00 kinda both.. it is a complex calculations. A long running functions involving IO and data. Well, IO only to partially dump some result after the image being built.

Comment: Then, put it in a worker thread.